# ta-lib c++, calculated macd not matched web

Tags: c++, finance, quantitative-finance, ta-lib

I'm using ta-lib c++ library to calculate MACD, but the result is totally different from what the website shows,
the real MACD is [444.39, 505.05, 248.02, -232.33, 100.39, -13.18],
but my result is [282.10, -74.12, -211.27, -460.82, -850.86]
I have set all the MAType to TA_MAType_EMA, but it makes no sense

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <ta-lib/ta_libc.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // init ta-lib context
    TA_RetCode retcode;
    retcode = TA_Initialize();
    assert(retcode == TA_SUCCESS);

    // comput moving average price
    TA_Real    close_price_array[100] = { 37924.41, 40849.89, 37952.37, 36564.58, 36844.22, 34719.71, 33156.65, 32858.22, 
                                          34212.01, 37118.35, 31924.17, 30327.18, 31757.38, 34459.95, 31952.8 , 31876.57, 
                                          32457.32, 31392.34, 34183.43, 37328.12, 36408.31, 35732.04, 37460.76, 35627.27, 
                                          39551.87, 34677.01, 33834.78, 31580.01, 39674.77, 40513.11, 40829.87, 38950.0 , 
                                          34555.33, 32091.45, 31737.83, 33506.67, 31695.17, 29190.91, 28779.14, 28153.95, 
                                          26617.04, 26911.93, 27360.51, 25625.24, 24019.43, 23230.15, 23450.3 , 23341.65, 
                                          23099.56, 23873.04, 23551.1 , 22553.6 , 23329.31, 20659.69, 19406.28, 19198.7 , 
                                          19215.36, 18401.98, 18106.72, 18134.91, 18347.36, 18806.82, 19213.0 , 19126.33, 
                                          19107.67, 18945.51, 19533.84, 18891.06, 19265.5 , 19306.92, 18116.34, 17505.0 , 
                                          16502.76, 16905.43, 19129.39, 19358.42, 18269.55, 18294.73, 18784.06, 18655.81, 
                                          18046.78, 17871.06, 17318.57, 16450.98, 16026.15, 15950.15, 16098.79, 16122.33, 
                                          15666.22, 15168.03, 15004.24, 15354.6 , 15342.63, 15411.23, 15077.18, 13911.95, 
                                          13708.92, 13492.15, 13797.96, 13854.39 };
    TA_Real    *p = close_price_array;

    cout.precision(8);
    
    TA_Integer out_begin = 0;
    TA_Integer out_nb_element = 0;

    TA_Real    outMACD[100] = { 0 };
    TA_Real    outMACDSignal[100] = { 0 };
    TA_Real    outMACDHist[100] = { 0 };
    

    retcode = TA_MACDEXT(0, 99,
        &close_price_array[0],
        12, TA_MAType_EMA  ,
        26, TA_MAType_EMA  ,
        9,  TA_MAType_EMA  ,
        &out_begin, &out_nb_element,
        outMACD, outMACDSignal, outMACDHist);

    assert(retcode == TA_SUCCESS);

    cout << "out_begin_index: " << out_begin << endl;
    cout << "out_nb_element: " << out_nb_element << endl;
    cout << "outMACD array: " << endl;
    for (auto &i : outMACD)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "outMACDSignal array: " << endl;
    for (auto &i : outMACDSignal)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "outMACDSignal array: " << endl;
    for (auto &i : outMACDHist)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;

    retcode = TA_Shutdown();
    assert(retcode == TA_SUCCESS);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNL6c.jpg)

Comment: And if you start it with `TA_MACDEXT(1, 99, &close_price_array[1],` you'll get another different result. Bcs many rolling indicators are sensitive to the data at the beginning, especially for small datasets. So when your website is starting to calculate its MACD? From the beginning if the year? From the beginning of ticket history?

Answer (score 0):

*[After comparing TA-lib results with Excel calculations]:* In your excel the 12-day EMA is calculated from the 1st day and its first value is the average on 12th day (8/13/2020) and the 26-day EMA is calculated from 1st day and first value is average on 26th day (26/13/2020). TA-Lib postpones the 12 day EMA calculation start to get its first value on the same day as first value of 26-day EMA. That means 12-day EMA is calculated from 8/16/2020 and it's first value is the average on (26/13/2020) as it's in 26-day EMA. So to adjust your excel to TA-Lib results you need to copy formula `=AVERAGE(B19:B30)` into the cell `C30`.

Another note is that TA-Lib's MACD outputs 3 arrays at once: macd, signal, histogram. And thus TA-Lib starts the output at the point it got meaningful values for all 3 result arrays. Thus you're getting result starting not from the point where 26-day EMA can be calculated, but from the point where Signal can be calculated (8 days later). So you shall compare talib_macd[1] with excel starting from cell `E38` instead of `E30`.